# How to remove numbers from an 2d array php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I've got an 2d array that stores data from my database table then puts it in a json file. And since I'm not calling my column names because it is dynamic, the array is adding it's incrementation (numbers) automatically with the table cell detail, I don't want this.

**Here is the json file example**

```
{"0":"1","Fix":"1","1":"Sunday, May 11, 2014","Date":"Sunday, May 11, 2014","2":"FT","Time":"FT","3":"Cardiff City","Home":"Cardiff City","4":"1-2","Score":"1-2","5":"Chelsea","Away":"Chelsea","6":"Cardiff City Stadium (27,716)","Stadium":"Cardiff City Stadium (27,716)"}
```

**I attempted to remove it in php like this**

```
//Select everything in table
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$tablename);

    //Storing the data into one arrays witk the ey => value
    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        //Store the data as a 2d array
        $json[] = $r;
    }

    foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
        # code...
        if(preg_match('/[0-9]/', $key)){
            unset($json[$key]);

        }else{

        }
    }

    //Display the JSOn data
    $o = fopen($tablename.'.json', 'w');
    echo fwrite($o, json_encode($json));
    fclose($o);
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current attempt? Also sounds like a good joob for `is_numeric()` instead of a regular expression

Comment: Can you `print_r($json)` before your `foreach` to see what the results of your query are returning?

Comment: That true I'll add that in. The script doesn't insert the data here it doesn't like something in the foreach loop

Comment: it looks like the json file I put in the description above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `MYSQL_ASSOC` as a second parameter of the `mysql_fetch_array()` function.

Comment: Do you mean like this  
 while($r=mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)){